# How do I properly input an sql where clause in VBA?

Tags: sql, excel, vba

The where clause in the code below is throwing me an error. I just can't seem to get the syntax right.

```
    today = Date
    monthBack = today - 30
    strSQL = ""
    strSQL = strSQL + "SELECT *"
    strSQL = strSQL + "FROM PROD.LABOR_ALLOCATION_HIST"
    strSQL = strSQL + "WHERE LaborDate BETWEEN today AND monthBack"
```

Comment: What line throws the error?  What is the error?  VBA?  Why are you adding strings?  VBA won't do that.

Comment: You'll also want spaces at the end of your lines your current code will read 'SELECT *FROM..._HISTWHERE...'

Comment: The final line is throwing the error, "incorrect syntax near the word BETWEEN"

Comment: `today` and `monthBack` are not dates. You need to use parameterized queries and a SqlCommand object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values of the variables need to be added to the SQL, not their names, and the values need to be in an appropriate format.

The following code will add the dates in `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

```vb
today = Date
monthBack = today - 30
strSQL = ""
strSQL = strSQL & "SELECT *"
strSQL = strSQL & "FROM PROD.LABOR_ALLOCATION_HIST"
strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE LaborDate BETWEEN '" & Format(today, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "' AND  '" & Format(monthBack, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "'"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
today = Date
    monthBack = today - 30
    strSQL = ""
    strSQL = strSQL & "SELECT *" & vbCrLf
    strSQL = strSQL & "FROM PROD.LABOR_ALLOCATION_HIST" & vbCrLf
    strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE LaborDate BETWEEN " & today & " AND " & monthBack
```

...but you'll need to convert `today` and `monthBack` to strings that contain something SQL will read as a valid date.

Comment: I guess the downvote is fair.  I failed to recognize the variables in the string that were not being played as variables.  I have updated my answer.  Maybe someone with more recent VBA experience can improve on my answer.  I haven't done VBA for about 20 years.

Comment: The downvote is because you didn't make any mention of parameterizing the variables, thus making it vulnerable to sql injection. Happy to remove it though

Comment: It's VBA.  Once Joe User can access SQL Server through Excel or PowerPoint, you have no idea what happens next.  The developer could be anybody.  You can't expect them to know or care about such things.  The logon should have permissions set such that SQL injection is not relevant.  The logon shouldn't be able to do any damage to the database or get to any sensitive data. (unless you consider PowerPoint a good tool to use to view sensitive data.)  If SQL injection via VBA is an issue, you may need a new DBA.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively without variables

```vb
strSQL = " SELECT * FROM PROD.LABOR_ALLOCATION_HIST" & _
         " WHERE DATEDIFF(day,LaborDate,GetDate()) BETWEEN 0 and 30"
```